# Hibernate. How can we set name of PK/FK using annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

We have hibernate-based system and customer wants to get human-readable names of PK and FK.
In our project we use annotated entity classes.

Is it renaming possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `@ForeignKey` annotation (the [Hibernate Annotation Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc) show an example under the "Single Association related annotations" chapter).